# How do I stop Apache2 from automatically starting on boot?

Tags: apache2, systemd, init.d

How do I stop Apache2 from automatically starting on boot? I can't seem to find an option that disables the automatic start-up when I turn on the machine.

Comment: Perhaps someone can be more specific, but I can point you in the right direction... in /etc, there are directories for rc*.d, which contain all the start/stop scripts, called, I think, init scripts.  You'll see links to scripts that are in /etc/init.d, and starting with either "k" or "s", for "kill" or "start", and a number which is the ordering.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the /etc/rcX.d directories, but I searched for it to find out about some nicer tool, than just manually renaming files (life is too short). `update-rc.d` has filled this void.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

On old,pre systemd distributions under `/etc/init.d/` you will find all the init scripts for different boot up services, like apache2, networking, etc.

Depending on which runlevel the computer starts in, different services are started.
So from the `/etc/init.d/` folder each "service" is linked to one/many/no run level folders named from `rc0.d` to `rc6.d`.

To keep things simple there is a tool for removing/adding these links, hence removing or adding scripts to and from start up.

**To disable** apache2 simply type:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

This disables apache2 at startup but is not removed so it can be enabled again. To remove the apache2 startup scripts do the following:

**To remove** apache2 simply type:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f  apache2 remove
```

###Doing this will cause all runlevel folders that are linked to apache2 to be removed.

Comment: chkconfig may also help - " chkconfig {service_name} off "

Comment: Doesn't work anymore: ```The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs. (...)```

Comment: @TomDogg, can you specify the versions you were working with? This answer works for Apache 2 on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: It's worth noting, the `-f` here means `Force removal of symlinks even if /etc/init.d/name still exists.`  As in, "if you're going to leave Apache2 installed, you gotta do it like tomodachi says.". Without the `-f`, you're telling it you've already uninstalled Apache 2, and it results in errors.

Comment: How to restore the service?

Comment: **Warning!** This will **REMOVE** the service! Use `sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable`.

Comment: You might want to stop it first, and THEN disable it. `sudo service apache2 graceful-stop`

Answer (score 260):

you could simply disable it by:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

and then if you would like to enable it again:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable
```

depending on the project i am working on, it is  handy to have the service conveniently available, if i wish to re-enable it.

Comment: `enable` gave me an error like `runlevel arguments (none) do not match LSB Default-Start values`, but `sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults` appears to have re-enabled it successfully.

Comment: @here `sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable` played as expected for me

Comment: On Ubuntu Trusty it tells me "The disable|enable API is not stable and might change in the future."

Comment: Doesn't work - `error: no runlevel symlinks to modify, aborting!`. However, apache2 is running and autostarts.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore: ```update-rc.d: error: no runlevel symlinks to modify, aborting!```

Comment: what's the difference between "disable" and "remove"?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp well, with systemd, *disable* will stop the service from automatically starting at boot and *mask* will disable the service completely by creating a simlink  to /dev/null.

Comment: @jutky can someone explain why this is better than tomodachi's answer, given the comment there that says the `-f` option is necessary if you want to keep apache2 around?

Comment: @nealmcb nothing personal, but "disable" sound less dangerous to me than "remove"

Comment: If encounter `update-rc.d: error: no runlevel symlinks to modify, aborting!`, recreate any below missing simlinks; then retry:
 /etc/rc0.d/K01<service>
 /etc/rc1.d/K01<service>
 /etc/rc2.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc3.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc4.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc5.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc6.d/K01<service>

Answer (score 103):

With `systemd` we can now use `systemctl` [commands](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemctl.1.html#commands) to prevent a service from automatically starting at boot.

here is an example:

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2
```

You will still be able to start and stop the service but it won't start up at boot.

Comment: on Linux Mint (ubuntu based) this doesn't exist and can't install it via apt-get install systemd >> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  systemd-services systemd-services:i386

Comment: Linux Mint is still based on Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu starts using systemd from 15.04 on.

Comment: @dragonmnl as twan163 said, systemd is for the newer versions (debian jessie or equivalent +)

Comment: @dragonmnl to search for available packages, run the following command: `apt-cache search systemd | grep systemd`

Comment: this worked great on Debian

Comment: the right answer for debian 9+

Comment: If encounter `update-rc.d: error: no runlevel symlinks to modify, aborting!`, recreate any below missing simlinks; then retry:
 /etc/rc0.d/K01<service>
 /etc/rc1.d/K01<service>
 /etc/rc2.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc3.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc4.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc5.d/S99<service>
 /etc/rc6.d/K01<service>

Comment: thank you! i use xampp for dev purposes. when i installed php7.3 from ondrej ppa (to use it with composer), the apache2 began to start on system boot, thus conflicting with xampp's embedded httpd. your proposed solution has worked for me: after running `sudo systemctl disable apache2` and rebooting, apache doesn't start up on boot anymore and thus xampp's embedded httpd has continued to work as it did earlier. thank you!  (ubuntu 18.10)

Comment: I did this for sshd and it no longer autostarts, but I also cannot start it manually with `sudo systemctl start sshd` because `Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found.`. Fixed it by reinstalling.

Answer (score 8):

Thought I'd just add to the answers by @gsullins and @tomodachi, for future readers who used the accepted answer.

If you've already used:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove
```

You can use the argument `defaults` to add apache2 back into the autostart

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults
```

Then you're able to enable/disable

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable
```