# How to disable the default apache server

Tags: apache2

I recently installed lampp and apache is unable to start because there is another web server already running. How do I disable whatever default server might be running in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: This will work no matter if *apache* or *nginx*, etc.: http://askubuntu.com/q/170640/62483

Answer (score 3):

Running the following command should work:

```
service {apache2,httpd} stop
```

and you may also run:

```
chkconfig apache2 off
```