# SSH service failing on Reboot

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, services, connection

I am working on Rock 5B which have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server OS (Download from radxa official page), I am facing a issue of ssh service, Whenever I reboot the device ssh service is getting failed. Through debugging I manually starting the service and I am able to do ssh.

Please use below mentioned as reference.
Kindly help me with this.

```
root@rock-5b:/home/rock# sudo service ssh status
�● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: >
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
```

Below is the contents of service file (ssh.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Official Ubuntu is on-topic here, you mention using a remix from raxda & not official Ubuntu; that is supported on SE Unix & Linux*

Answer (score 0):

This question is off topic but the answer applies to standard versions of Ubuntu as well.

Your output says that the service is disabled. In order for the service to start at boot, you will need to use systemd to [enable](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemctl.1.html#commands) the service.

**Run the following command to enable the service:**

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

Once a service is enabled, it will automatically start at boot.

---

Conversely, you would [disable a service to prevent it from starting at boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/675756/167115):

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh
```